# How to convert icon widget to ImageProvider

Tags: flutter

I want to use the Material design icons of flutter in my program, for that, I need to use the Icon widget. I have one network image (NetworkImage widget) and I want to display the Material design icon if there is an empty URL.

```
Container(
      width: 48.0,
      height: 48.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: imgLink.isEmpty
                ? Icon(Icons.person_outline)
                : NetworkImage(
                    imgLink,
                  ),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
    ),
```

it shows error as icons is not a subtype of ImageProvider. Now how I can convert Icon to ImageProvider or any other way.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to create your own provider that converts the icon:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconImageProvider extends ImageProvider<IconImageProvider> {
  final IconData icon;
  final double scale;
  final int size;
  final Color color;

  IconImageProvider(this.icon, {this.scale = 1.0, this.size = 48, this.color = Colors.white});

  @override
  Future<IconImageProvider> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) => SynchronousFuture<IconImageProvider>(this);

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(IconImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) => OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));

  Future<ImageInfo> _loadAsync(IconImageProvider key) async {
    assert(key == this);

    final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);
    final textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl);
    textPainter.text = TextSpan(
      text: String.fromCharCode(icon.codePoint),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: size.toDouble(),
        fontFamily: icon.fontFamily,
        color: color,
      ),
    );
    textPainter.layout();
    textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset.zero);
    final image = await recorder.endRecording().toImage(size, size);
    return ImageInfo(image: image, scale: key.scale);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) return false;
    final IconImageProvider typedOther = other;
    return icon == typedOther.icon && scale == typedOther.scale && size == typedOther.size && color == typedOther.color;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(icon.hashCode, scale, size, color);

  @override
  String toString() => '$runtimeType(${describeIdentity(icon)}, scale: $scale, size: $size, color: $color)';
}
```

This is a standard `ImageProvider`, all the stock ones look much like this. The actual conversion is inside `_loadAsync()`. Rather simple, just a normal `Canvas` operation to draw the icon as text (it *is* text, actually).

Comment: For some reason, this code above fails when using CupertinoIcons.  I just get the small square with X inside to indicate (I'm guessing) code-point not found for this font.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Image in `BoxDecoration` of `Container` only support the [ImageProvider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html) class which have
the following Implementers
`AssetBundleImageProvider`, `FileImage`, `MemoryImage`, `NetworkImage`, `ResizeImage`, `ScrollAwareImageProvider` so it doesn't support the icon widget because icon widget has its own [IconData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html) class so that's why flutter giving you error, "icons is not a subtype of ImageProvider".